# Angular $compile throws error for non-HTML string with quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use `$compile` to inject HTML provided by a user into a directive.

```js
module.directive('foo', ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return {
        // ...
        link: function($scope, el) {
            // ...
            var userHtml = userConfigObject.content;
            var compiledHtml = $compile(userHtml)($scope);
            myElement.innerContent.html(compiledHtml);
        }
    };
 }]);
```

I want to allow the user to inject a string (e.g. `"Let's party!"`) or some HTML (e.g. `'<div ng-click="foo()">Click to party!</div>'`).

However, when the user only provides a string with a quote (or any other "non-valid HTML"), the `$compile` statement gives the following error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Let's party!

(this error ultimately came from jQuery's Sizzle logic).

The only way I can think of solving this (while still allowing both non-HTML and HTML strings) is using this instead.

```js
var stepHtml = '<div>' + userConfigObject.content + '</div>';
```

so that `$compile` always receives a valid HTML string. However, I rather not unnecessarily wrap the content in a `div`.

### Solutions that did not work

I tried escaping the user content beforehand (replacing quote with the HTML code), but that didn't work.

I also tried to use `$sanitize` thinking it would escape characters or something, but that didn't work either.

Finally, the `ng-click` attribute did not work when I used `$interpolate`.

Any ideas on how I could use `$compile` on non HTML strings? Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users are actually entering in directives like `ng-click` then you could see if the html has elements in it:

```
var userHtml = userConfigObject.content;
var $tempDiv  = angular.element('<div>').html(userHtml);
if(!$tempDiv.children().length){
  userHtml = $tempDiv 
}

var compiledHtml = $compile(userHtml)($scope);
myElement.innerContent.html(compiledHtml);
```

If there are text nodes mixed with elements in the root then your best bet would be always wrap in a container

Comment: But OP also wanted to make `ng-click` work, that's why he went for `$compile`ing element manually. I think he should pass `userConfigObject.content` to some function which will encode the HTML so that he can `$compile` that string correctly

Comment: @PankajParkar ok...think i have solution now

Comment: @PankajParkar will still be problem maybe if text nodes in root as well as elements. Not really sure and not curious enough to build tests

Comment: But we are wrapping content with div anyway.. so i don't think so that will happen

Comment: @PankajParkar not sure. Think of `"Click to party!<span>Click here</span>"`

Comment: @charlietfl Close, but as you mentioned, I get the same syntax error when the user inputs mixed text/HTML nodes.

Comment: Any specific reason you can't wrap everything?

Comment: No *real* reason, I just rather not add extra `div`s if I can avoid it. If I don't find a better solution in a few days I'll certainly accept your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Alternative would be find an html entities snippet( not hard to find) and loop over the text nodes in root with it.